# mysql update (in) more than 1 row

Tags: mysql, sql

```
UPDATE tbl_bonuses AS B 
INNER JOIN tbl_member AS V 
ON B.recepient_code = V.user_id 
SET B.points = B.points + 15, B.ctr = B.ctr + 15
WHERE user_id IN (SELECT user_id from tbl_member LIMIT 10);
```

ERROR:

```
#1235 - This version of MySQL doesn't yet support 'LIMIT & IN/ALL/ANY/SOME subquery'
```

any other way to multiple update with multiple argument without using (in)?

Comment: LIMIT without ORDER BY is pretty much meaningless, rendering your whole query nonsensical! I do like that optimistic error message though.

Comment: haha . i will always put ORDER BY ... sometimes i look into my database with numerical order ... it goes 1,10,11,12,13,14,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Wrap your subquery inside a derived table

```
UPDATE tbl_bonuses AS B 
INNER JOIN tbl_member AS V 
ON B.recepient_code = V.user_id 
SET B.points = B.points + 15, B.ctr = B.ctr + 15
WHERE user_id IN (SELECT user_id FROM (
                                       SELECT user_id from tbl_member LIMIT 10
                                      ) t 
                 );
```

Comment: @hordanmichel It's still nonsensical, though ;-)

Answer (score 1):

MySQL does not support LIMIT in subqueries for certain subquery operators:

mysql> SELECT * FROM t1
    ->   WHERE s1 IN (SELECT s2 FROM t2 ORDER BY s1 LIMIT 1);
ERROR 1235 (42000): This version of MySQL doesn't yet support
 'LIMIT & IN/ALL/ANY/SOME subquery'
The optimizer is more mature for joins than for subqueries, so in many cases a statement that uses a subquery can be executed more efficiently if you rewrite it as a join.

An exception occurs for the case where an IN subquery can be rewritten as a SELECT DISTINCT join. Example:

SELECT col FROM t1 WHERE id_col IN (SELECT id_col2 FROM t2 WHERE condition);
That statement can be rewritten as follows:

SELECT DISTINCT col FROM t1, t2 WHERE t1.id_col = t2.id_col AND condition;
But in this case, the join requires an extra DISTINCT operation and is not more efficient than the subquery.

please refer this [link](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/subquery-restrictions.html)